# How to put XML content in reverse order?

Tags: php, xml, reverse

I tried a few solutions already posted here, but nothing seems to work. That might be, because I am really not that familiar with php or xml. I just need to output xml for xcoding. So hopefully someone can shed some light, on how I can reverse the order of my xml, so that the last entry is on top. 
My last try what with:

```
$query = array_reverse($doc->xpath('query'));
```

but it did not like it ,e.g. it did not work.

So here is my code in order to create my xml document:

```
<?php 

if(!$dbconnect = mysql_connect('localhost', '-', '-')) {
echo "Connection failed to the host 'localhost'.";
exit;
} // if
if (!mysql_select_db('-')) {
echo "Cannot connect to database '-'";
exit;
} // if

$table_id = 'table1';
$query = "SELECT Name,Age,Sex FROM $table_id";

$dbresult = mysql_query($query, $dbconnect);

// create a new XML document
$doc = new DomDocument('1.0');

// create root node
$root = $doc->createElement('root');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

// process one row at a time
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult)) {

// add node for each row
$occ = $doc->createElement($table_id);
$occ = $root->appendChild($occ);

// add a child node for each field
foreach ($row as $fieldname => $fieldvalue) {

$child = $doc->createElement($fieldname);
$child = $occ->appendChild($child);

$value = $doc->createTextNode($fieldvalue);
$value = $child->appendChild($value);

} // foreach
} // while


// get completed xml document
$xml_string = $doc->saveXML();
$doc->save("yolo.xml") 

//echo $xml_string;
?>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with a query like `SELECT 1,2,3,4`? That will only get the literal numbers 1,2,3,4 for every row in your table.

Comment: The proper course of action is not to reverse your XML, but probably to reverse your query order.

Comment: Oh well, sorry, I deleted what was initially in there, I will edit it, and put it back. Could you tell me how to reverse the query order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to issue an SQL query which returns results in the order you want.  The SQL query you have here has no `ORDER BY` clause, so results come back in no particular order.

However, you can also reverse the order of results as you add them to your XML document: instead of *appending* new child nodes for each row, *prepend* them. Replace this line:

```
$occ = $root->appendChild($occ);
```

With

```
$occ = $root->insertBefore($occ, $root->firstChild);
```

Also generally speaking it's best to finish building a tree of XML before you add it to the document.